# Windows opened instead of Ubuntu after Ubuntu installation

Tags: dual-boot

Recently, I decided to install Ubuntu after a roommate told me about. I installed Ubuntu using a USB while still keeping my Windows 10. At the end it said that he installation was successful and it needed to restart my computer. But when it restarted it just opened straight into windows. So I closed my laptop (HP 2000 Notebook PC) and opened the boot device menu and clicked on Ubuntu and it still opened windows. Does anyone know how I can opened Ubuntu instead of Windows? Also can you please keep the answer simple because I don't know much about operating systems. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: See the "Troubleshooting" section in https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi